# Mac Book Pro 2.2 (2008) Core 2 Duo, display and trackpad stopped working

Tags: macbook-pro, trackpad, gpu

My Mac Book Pro 2.2 (2008) Core 2 Duo, was working properly, and after waking it up (open the lid), the display was black...

It happened to me before and the other times I reckon it was some kind of bug with it not *understanding* it was meant to wake up (nothing a lid close, wait a bit and open lid wouldn't solve).

This time none of my previous *solutions* worked, and I forced a shutdown and then started it, and it remained with a blank (black) screen.

I can connect to it via the screen sharing application, and everything is working except the trackpad, the cursor doesn't move. Incidentally, connecting an external USB mouse, doesn't work, the cursor also doesn't move. (the cursor via screen sharing at least works).

By connecting to it remotely, I can go to the system preferences and can see that under the monitors preferences, it shows the standard display resolutions, and I connected an external monitor and nothing, so I assume the graphic card is gone.

**So symptoms are:**

- no display, no external display;
- no USB mouse (but it does read USB pen drives)

**What I've done so far:**

- reseted VRAM
- started from an external system

None of these worked and what puzzles me is why doesn't the USB external mouse work? (the rest seems to indicate the graphic card + trackpad are seriously damaged).

**What can I do? is there a solution for this?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Mac arrived today after behing fixed under the extendend warranty for the NVidia graphics card problem (basically NVidia "admits" the card has a problem and so the authorized apple support replaces the card).

Strange that the trackpad was affected and that the external mouse wouldn't work, but averyhing works ok now, so I have to assume it was all related to the graphics card.

Answer (score 1):

my 2008 santa rosa 2.2GHz MacBook Pro has suffered both the graphic chip problem (no picture on screen but accessible through screen sharing apps or ext monitor), and the trackpad cable problem (no response from keyboard or trackpad although ext mouse and keyboard function ok). Both are common faults on this model. Graphics prob repairable under the special warranty extension from Apple. Trackpad cable fairly easy using ifixit.com guide.

When my graphics card was in broken mode, (it was intermittent), it would not show up in the Graphics/Displays section of System Information (Lion); the Intel chipset would show up there instead; so thus you can check if you have the graphics chip (poor solderflow) problem. It would however give me the output to an external monitor ok (?!*)

It sounds as though you might have suffered both at the same time...although your ext mouse should work(?!*)

Comment: thanks for the reply, incidently, my mac came today and it was just a problem with the graphic card (strange that it affected the trackpad + using external mouse, but the important thing is that it works now).